# Problem when trying to create a digital ocean app from gitlab source

Tags: digital-ocean, digital-ocean-apps

I am trying to create an app in digital ocean using source code from gitlab and I get the error "no detected components".
Any ideas?

Comment: If you find a solution, please let me know! I have the same problem. gitlab-ci.yaml ready, and I have no idea what DigitalOcean wants from me.

Answer (score 2):

make sure that your project's index file is named index.html. in my case i had a project where the index file was named landing.html changing this to index.html fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

digitalocean cannot detect the folder of your project. After selecting your GitHub project branch go ahead and specify the directory which has your project contents. for instance `\src`.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error for my django project, and this was because I did not create the file requirements.txt. So, if your App project is in python and you use Poetry for dependency management, you should run the command

```
poetry export --without-hashes --format=requirements.txt > requirements.txt
```

Then commit and pust to your repo again. Then it would work.